# Assistance with Level Shifter

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, signal, level-shifting, homework

[image: Level Shifter]

I have a front end module that generates an ECG signal that varies from +/- 1.5 V. I need to shift this signal so it goes from 0-3V. I have looked at some other threads to try and understand the circuit better, and I found a thread from a few years ago featuring a very similar project to this one (The only difference was the input and output values, being +/- 2.5 and 0-5V), but all I was able to glean from that was that R2 and R1 should be a 2:1 ratio, but other than that I'm not really sure where to go. I still need to find the V+ voltage when Vin is +1.5, Resistor values for R3 and R4, and the gain, but I am pretty stumped.

[image: My non-functioning LTSpice Circuit]

[image: This is the voltage graph I get no matter where on the circuit I click, which is very confusing.]

Comment: Why do you have the "feeling" that R2 and R1 should be 2:1 ratio? Consider the situation when Vout = 0 and Vin = -1.5V. P.S. If this is homework, please add the homework tag and show your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I clarified the issue that I am having a bit more, as per your suggestion.

Comment: Do you need shift only, or also amplification? What range is useful for the next stage - is it a maximum of 3V, or something higher?

Comment: Also, what is the maximum desirable frequency to pass through this stage?

Comment: Finally, you need to modify your diagram to show what the far end of your voltage sources connects to. I'm sure they aren't dangling in real life.

Comment: When Vout is 0, the node between R3 and R4 must be 0 as well. So V- and V+ must also be 0. So you should be able to determine R1 and R2 as they voltage divide 5V and whatever Vin causes Vout to be 0. Comment when you get that far.

Comment: To Reinderien; I only need to shift, the conditions laid out in my initial post are the only conditions. I just have a voltage input (Vin) which functions as a sine wave with an amplitude of +/- 1.5, and I need to translate that into a sine wave with an amplitude from 0-3V. There isn't really a next stage. I just need to find the resistor values, V+, and Gain for that circuit.

Comment: I'm sure there is a next stage (planned or otherwise); but anyway. I'll roll with the question as it stands.

Comment: What is the output impedance of the previous stage?

Comment: The assignment doesn't mention anything about a previous or next stage, sorry.

Comment: @NK_345 You have two possible arrangements -- an inverting summation or a non-inverting summation. You show the non-inverting approach, so I'll assume that is the one that is desired. In all cases with a non-inverting approach your (+) input terminal will experience an attenuated dynamic range of the input signal. No way to avoid that fact, using resistor dividers. So you must include gain on the (-) terminal side in order to recover that loss.

Comment: @NK_345 Also, due to %-error for resistor values, you'll find this to perform rather poorly from build-to-build. You may be able to achieve the goal using exact resistor values. But once you try and build it, you will find significant "issues."

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frmz3M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I won't do the derivation math for you, since this is homework. I'm sure your prof will want to see that, so basically your thought process should be:

- I need a gain of one, because the input voltage isn't multiplied by anything
- R1 and R2 form a voltage divider between 5V and Vin
- U2 needs a super-unary gain multiplied by the sub-unary gain of R1/R2 to get a total gain of one
- The constant term introduced by R1/R2, when multiplied by the gain, should equal 1.5.

In a real-life system, the following (at least) would be different:

- You would (probably) need to care about the output impedance of the previous stage, because - if the buffer of U1 is not present - this will interact with the passive network of R1/R2
- You would definitely know what range the next stage will accept, and have specific reasons for choosing it (i.e. it's an ADC, or some other conditioning circuit or filter with known constraints)
- You would definitely have at least some ballpark idea of bandwidth required, and may want to introduce capacitors across R3 and/or from the non-inverting input of U2 to ground
- You would know what power constraints are in place and what leakage characteristics U1 and U2 have, and scale your resistors accordingly

Answer (score 0):

R1-R2 just builds a voltage divider between the two sources.
the OpAmp and R3-R4 just follows the voltage on the center of the first divider with a scaling factor defined by the second pair of resistors..

Any more questions? Giving the resistors dimension depends on specs of the real world parts. I have not seen that.